# Modify value in unordered_set

Tags: c++

I have the following structure:

```
struct User 
{
    string name;
    bool flag;
    int score;

    bool operator==(const User& user) const
    {
        return name == user.name;
    }
}

namespace std {
    template<>
        struct hash<User>
        {
            size_t operator()(const User& user) const
            {
                return hash<string>{}(user.m_nickname);
            }
        };
}
```

After that I want to use User with unordered_set container, but after reading another portion of data I want to modify user score\flag etc, therefore it wont affect the hash value, because I know that all users will have unique names beforehand.

In my program I use something like that:

```
unordered_set<User> set;
while(true)
{    
    User user = *set.find({name});
    user.score++;
}
```

But after my user object goes out of scope and I find it one more time values remain the same as they were before modifying. How I can solve this problem and maybe I should use other container? I have chosen this one because of O(1) complexity.

Comment: Shouldn't you be modifying the return value of the set.find directly? You're pretty much modifying a copy of the value in the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Map, `unordered_map`, where the key is the name and the value is User.

Comment: I agree with this. Using unordered sets is a nightmare for this use case whereas a map is easy and straightforward.

Answer (score 11):

In an `unordered_set<>` each object's value is its key.  Hence, the objects can't change.

One way you can get around this is by making the non-key members mutable.

That is, change

```
bool flag;
int score;
```

to

```
mutable bool flag;
mutable int score;
```

Also, you're modifying a copy.

Change

```
User user = *set.find({name});
```

to

```
auto &user = *set.find({name});
```