# insert into a C++ unordered_map with known hash-value

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set, const-correctness

I have a "table" that is a `std::unorderd_set` of, basically, `std::vector<int>` with a hash-function that returns the XOR of the hash-values of all elements in the vector. Thus, the hash-value of a vector depends only on the elements, not on their order.

Now, I am implementing a dynamic programming on said table that is supposed to first check if a vector already is in the table and, if not, compute a table entry for it. This computation, however, might change the order of the elements of the vector. So here's what I want to do, roughly:

```cpp
using Entry = vector<int>;
using Table = unordered_set<Entry, set_hash>; // set_hash is the XOR-based hasher
Table dp_table;

const Entry& query(const vector<int>& q) {
  auto [iter, success] = dp_table.emplace(q);
  // alternatively, I can dp_table.find() here, computing the hash of q
  if(success) {
    compute_entry(*iter); // I want to permute *iter here (doesn't change its hash)
    // alternatively, I can dp_table.emplace() here, computing the hash of q a second time
  }
  return *iter;
}
```

Now, the way I wrote it here doesn't work because `*iter` is const. Understandable, as the `unordered_set` cannot be sure my modification doesn't change the hash (but I know it doesn't). Here's possible solutions and why I don't like them:

1. I could use the "alternatively"-way, but that means I have to repeat the (costly) hash-calculation which I would really like to avoid. I'd like to be able to tell the `unordered_set` "hey, this is the hash-value of that thing, trust me", but that's not possible.
2. I could wrap the `Entry` in a class in which I declare the vector `mutable` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614433/modify-value-in-unordered-set)), but that means I loose const-correctness whenever I deal with elements of the table. Also, I think modifying a const-item is officially UB.
3. I could modify the hasher such that it stores the hash with each item and just takes this cached hash instead of recomputing the hash whenever it sees an item with a precomputed hash, but that's dangerous if ever I do change the vector and forget to clear the cached hash. Also it takes up additional space in memory, which I want to avoid.

So that's my problem and why I dislike all the solutions I could come up with. Do you have a better idea how to solve this? It's much appreciated :)

Comment: So basically you want to modify vectors in unorderd_set but can not do it because unordered_set is designed to not allow that? Very interesting to hear, but what is the question?

Comment: isn't this what `std::unordered_map` good at?

Comment: the 3rd point is unavoidable, if you want to make it publicly mutable, you risk the hash inconsistency.

Comment: If you change order of the elements behind the `unorderded_set`s back, you may end up with two equal `vector<int>`s. Example `vector<int>{1,2}` and `vector<int>{2,1}`  have the same hash but does not compare equal, so the `unordered_set` would store both. If you now change the order in one of those `vector`s, you'll have a situation that should not be possible.

Comment: @TedLyngmo good point. I can guarantee though that, for each `vector<int>` my table contains at most one permutation of that vector.

Comment: @ÖöTiib the question is, roughly, "is there maybe any other way to go about this?" (a way that maybe I like better than the 3 ways above)

Comment: Ok, then version 2 should work. It wont be UB unless the class containing the vector is declared `const`. Store the calculated hash value in the class and only recalculate it when needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh, that's interesting, thanks for the comment! So do I get that right that the vector is not `const` but the `unordered_set` just gives me a const-reference to it and modifying a non-const object to which I only have a const-reference is not UB? Cool :)

Comment: @igel You're welcome :) It could look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/E4ejbMn84). I made `operator==` use the actual hash value here. If you _can_ use it, it'll be faster than comparing the whole vectors but it may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the calculated hash value together with the vector:

```cpp
class Entry {
public:
    std::size_t hash() const { return m_hash; }
private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
    std::size_t m_hash{};
};

template <> struct std::hash<Entry> {
    size_t operator()(const Entry& e) const { return e.hash(); }
};
```

Then only recalculate the hash value when performing operations that actually affects the hash value.

When you need to perform an operation on the vector that changes it in any way, just extract it, make the changes and reinsert it:

```cpp
std::unordered_set<Entry> s;
Entry e;
auto [sit, _] = s.insert(e);
    
auto node = s.extract(sit);
node.value().operation_that_does_not_alter_the_hash();
s.insert(std::move(node));
```

Since the member function `operation_that_does_not_alter_the_hash()` won't alter the hash value, it won't need to recalculate it. When reinserting the node into the `unordered_set`, it'll call the member function `hash()` which will return the precalculated value.

If you on the other hand call `operation_that_does_alter_the_hash()`, that function should then recalculate the hash and store that. Again, reinserting the node will be done in the same way and no extra recalculation of the hash value will be needed.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sva7s13n8)

Comment: Right, this is a cleaner version of my approach number 3. It still has the disadvantage of having to store 8 more bytes per table entry but I suspect this is OK given that each entry carries a massive vector anyways...
What I ended up doing was something like your godbolt link, minus the hash-cache, so `const Entry` allows permuting the elements of the vector arbitrarily.

I'll still accept this answer on behalf of your comment leading to what I wanted, I suppose :)

Comment: @igel  _"OK given that each entry carries a massive vector anyways"_  - Yes, that was my reasoning too. If there had been very few elements in the vectors, then recalculating the hash values would probably not have been so bad. _" something like your godbolt link"_ - Yes, sure, that's a variant of that theme and should also work.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I ended up with a slight modification of Ted's [code](https://godbolt.org/z/E4ejbMn84): I wrapped the `vector<int>` in a class `Entry` declaring the vector member `mutable` and having a function that allows permuting the `vector<int>` arbitrarily. This is guaranteed to keep the hash in tact and has none of the disadvantages I mentioned in my previous approaches.

```cpp
class Entry {
protected:
    mutable std::vector<int> data;
public:
    void permute_data(const Permutation& perm) const { ... }
    ...
};
```